# Write a function that shuffles a string of characters using a binKey

Tags: python, string, shuffle, bin

This is the question and def function setup:

> shuffleString(myString, binKey) - return myShufString.

Write a function that shuffles a string of characters, `myString`, using `binKey`.  Here's the idea.  We form a new empty string `myShufString`, which we then build by concatenating characters from either the beginning or end of `myString`, depending on whether `binKey[i]` is 0 or 1, starting with i=0 and cycling through `binKey` as necessary. Your function should be of the form `shuffleString(myString, binKey)` and should return `myShufString`.

**Hint:** You will probably want to form a list of the characters from `myString` and use the list method pop within a for loop over the length of `myString`.  This way you will not have to keep track of which characters from the ends of `myString` have already been used and added to `myShufString`.  You will call this function in step 5 to shuffle your alphabet that you created in step 1.

Here's an example. Suppose `myString = 'abcdefgh'` and `binKey = '101'`.

Then `myShufString = 'hagfbedc'`

Reason why:

We build `myShufString` as follows.

0) Form a list of the characters in `myString`, and call it `myList`, so:

```
myList = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'].
```

1) Start with an empty string: `myShufString = ''`

2) Since `binKey[0] = '1'`, pop the 'h' from the end of `myList` and concatenate to `myShufString`.

3) Since `binKey[1] = '0'`, pop the 'a' from the beginning of `myList` and concatenate to `myShufString`.

4) Since `binKey[2] = '1'`, pop the 'g' from the end of `myList` and concatenate to `myShufString`.

5) Now we have reached the end of `binKey`, so we cycle back to the beginning.

6) Since `binKey[0] = '1'`, pop the 'f' from the end of myList and concatenate to `myShufString`.

7) Since `binKey[1] = '0'`, pop the 'b' from the beginning of `myList` and concatenate to `myShufString`.

I got this so far:

```
def shuffleString(myString, binKey):
    myShufString = ""
    myList = list(myString)
    for string in range(len(myString)):
        if binKey[i] == '0':
            myShufString += myList.pop(0)
        else:
            myShufString += myList.pop(-1)
```

Should I use elif instead of else, or is this okay?
And not sure how the pop and `binKey` command works... Don't know how to do the rest...

EDIT:
I got the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

```
decryptCS8Cipher("That Sam-I-Am. That Sam-I-Am.  I do not like that Sam-I-Am.","decaf")
```

File "C:\Users\Elizabeth\Dropbox\CMPSC 8\lab05\lab05_function.py", line 54, in

decryptCS8Cipher

```
shufAlph = shuffleString(alphabet, binKey)
```

File "C:\Users\Elizabeth\Dropbox\CMPSC 8\lab05\lab05_function.py", line 18, in shuffleString

```
if binKey[i] == '0':
```

NameError: global name 'i' is not defined

I don't know what to do for the string and i variables!
Please help! Thank you!

Comment: I assume this is a homework question, in which case you should tag it as "homework"

Answer (score 0):

A couple hints, since this is a homework question:

You have some problems with your variables `i` and `string`. Think about what they represent and where they come from.

As for `else` vs. `elif` think about what values `binKey[i]` can take on, and what the result of the if statement for each of those values will be.